# Verify the Signed Artifactory webhook auth header

Tags: artifactory, hmac

i am trying to implement A Artifactory webhook on artifact upload event.

Following this documentation
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/webhooks

I am using pre-defined web hook with payload signing using a secret.

Web hook is working fine. But i am not sure on the validation on the server side.

I understand that we have to verify the signed content in `x-jfrog-event-auth` using the secret and validate with the payload.

But i am not sure if the secret signed or HMAC hashed.
For signature verification i need to the Signature algorithm to be used . Also if there is PKI (public key, private key) available.

I tried doing HMAC hash check with SHA256, the value in the auth header does not match the HMAC hash of the payload.

Best Regards,
Saurav